# Generate all tuple possible based on three lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, combinations, python-itertools

**Interesting answers, allow me to modify the question.**

After some change on the code I got this:

```
#coding:utf-8

import itertools


stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 25]
for L in range(5, 6):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        subset = list(subset)
        subset.extend([7, 9, 11, 15, 19, 23, 6, 12, 14, 24])
        print(subset)
```

the output of it is like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 15, 19, 23, 6, 12, 14, 24]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 9, 11, 15, 19, 23, 6, 12, 14, 24]
...
```

It generates approximately 3000 lines.

It did all possible combination with five numbers of the list stuff and add to every single combination (subset) the another list (subset.extend([7, 9, 11, 15, 19, 23, 6, 12, 14, 24])). It seems to be right, I'm not sure.

But what I really want it to do is:

1 - Input three lists (pair and unpair)

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
pair = [2 , 6, 12, 20, 16, 10, 22]
unpair = [1, 5, 11, 19, 23, 25, 13, 17]
```

2 - Than the program will generate all combinations of 4 numbers from the 7 numbers of pair and will do the same with unpair, generating all combinations of 4 numbers from the 8 numbers of unpair, and will bind it together generating a list with 8 number of al possible combinations of 4 numbers from pair combined with 4 number from unpair like:

```
[2, 12, 20, 10, 1, 5, 19, 23]
[2, 12, 20, 10, 5, 19, 25, 13]
...
```

3 - Than for each line from the combination of pair and unpair generated it will complete with a 7 numbers combination from the list stuff generating a list with 15 numbers without repeating a number like

```
[2, 12, 20, 10, 1, 5, 19, 23, 25, 3, 4, 8, 17, 21, 22]
[2, 12, 20, 10, 5, 19, 25, 13, 3, 4, 8, 17, 21, 22, 11]
...
```

Here is where I got stuck. How to generate a combination for each list and bind them generating a 15 numbers list without repeating a number and a sequence.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you mean. Can you give some example output?

Comment: This is a very cryptic question, you really need to add what you consider input and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

you can just manually code that logic in your for loop:

```
for combo in itertools.combinations(stuff, 15):
    if set(combo).issuperset(pair) and set(combo).issuperset(unpair):
        print(combo)
```

Note: This particular code only works when "stuff" has no duplicates